Mitigating Single Point of Failure in a Distributed Blockchain Network Setup(Substrate & Polkadot)
We have deployed a blockchain network using five cloud machines distributed across various geographical locations, with each machine running a specific node type crucial for the network’s functionality:

First Server (Boot/RPC Node): Acts as the primary access point for the network, holds the complete blockchain ledger, and facilitates communication between other nodes. Local node identity: 12D3KooWAZNJ7*****************P1VUwQnZxiDQdQfiwM. A proxy server is also configured on this machine, allowing us to view block data at Polkadot Explorer.
Second Server (Validator-1): Port forwarded to the Boot/RPC node.
Third Server (Archive Node): Port forwarded to the Boot/RPC node. A proxy server configured for extracting data from the genesis block to the current block.
Fourth Server (Validator-2): Port forwarded to the Boot/RPC node.
Fifth Server (Validator-3): Port forwarded to the Boot/RPC node.

Roles:

Validator Nodes (Validator-1, Validator-2, Validator-3): Contribute to the consensus mechanism by verifying and validating transactions.
Archive Node: Stores the entire blockchain history, ensuring data persistence and retrievability.


Network Connectivity:
All nodes connect to the Boot/RPC node using its public IP address and the previously obtained local node identity. Communication between the Boot/RPC node and other nodes is established using port forwarding.
Single Point of Failure:
The Boot/RPC node acts as a single point of failure. If this node goes down, the entire network becomes unavailable.
Question:
I am looking for advice on how to mitigate this single point of failure. What strategies or configurations could be implemented to enhance the resilience of our network? Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your help.
